# How to specify the generic typing when instantiating a class which allows a value of type or a value of a derived type

Tags: typescript

Why does this TypeScript code...

```js
interface Base {
    prop1: string
}

interface Derived extends Base {
    prop2: string
}

class Collection<T> {
  items: T[] = []
  add(item: T): T {
    this.items.push(item)
    return item
  }
}

const col = new Collection<Base>()
col.add({
    prop1: 'value1',
    prop2: 'value2'
})

// Note this work around, which demonstrates that this is perfectly workable without the typing
console.log(
  (
    col.add({
      prop1: 'value1',
      prop2: 'value2'
    } as any) as any
  )
  .prop2
)
```

(see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChkHIAOUA9kQIwBcyGYUoA5rgL666iSyIoAi0wAG4QAJsggAPSCBEY0mHPkIlyAJhp0GIZm1wIANpjkBhUvv0QEYYKRAAeACoA+ZHgLBIAWww0HAbQBdZABeZEClOBERAAoPCE9fAEpfVyUCMAALYAwAOjjvHKIAVwwM2K9EtOQoCDAiqBBkfKU2XQRbOmR2-RDkEAgAd2RTc0trWzt0LCdoyu6cyJi3ZTJKGgByQTh9IogKdYAaKpUidWRN7d3VddZK3AB6e+QAOVJIZEzs5AHSKABrZBwMhFGQHb5ZBAZZAieIdehwSByTIIj5ZORfIjQGBjfQAT2+vz+cAARhZvh4MqQimBUSgwLiiEw9B0zBAcvpSIxokpuYQumYFlFoss+SdqOctjs9ocqgQTmcLlLrlUWIC5HAQLjEmrAZqlJUCIVVqpcIkgA))

...produce this error...

```
Argument of type '{ prop1: string; prop2: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Base'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'prop2' does not exist in type 'Base'. Did you mean to write 'prop1'?
```

More specifically, ***how can I specify that I want to create an instance of `Collection` that accepts items of type `Base` and any and all derived interface types (but no other types) without specifying a union of all derived types?***

> Based on the responses so far, I would guess that this is not possible in the current (4.5.4) version of TypeScript.

Comment: Uhhh what are you doing putting a `string` as the key of a `WeakMap`?  That'll give you a runtime error and TypeScript doesn't like it either (widening from `string` to the object wrapper `String` isn't the way to fix this).  Since your question apparently has nothing to do with this sort of thing, could you [edit] to remove it?  You could just use a regular `Map` instead of a `WeakMap`, right?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't like `string` but it's okay with `String`. Using a string seemed useful here to keep the example simple.

Comment: You understand that your example, while simple, explodes at runtime, right?  Do you want that to happen?  If not, can you fix it?  If so, why?  If you don't care, can you fix it (so that nobody else has to figure out what's going on with it)?

Comment: Anyway [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAvBvW) is the approach I'd take making an answer here, but it might not be different enough from [Alex Wayne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70777378/2887218) to bother.  Good luck!

Comment: Updated. Hopefully, this new example is more palatable.

Answer (score 1):

Side stepping entirely the "why" of your code example, I don't think this has anything to do with `WeakMap` or extended interfaces at all. So I'm going to *vastly* simplify this problem:

```
type A = { str: string }
const test1: A = { str: 'string', num: 123 }
// Type '{ str: string; num: number; }' is not assignable to type 'A'.
//  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'num' does not exist in type 'A'.(2322)
```

Typescript makes a lot of judgement calls with its errors. And here its deciding this probably a mistake because you are directly assigning an object literal to a type that is missing some of those literals properties. This causes the type system to "forget" those extra properties, resulting in them being inaccessible.

However, this works fine:

```
type A = { str: string }
const test2Data = { str: 'string', num: 123 }
const test2: A = test2Data
```

This is because the `test2Data` is its own value and type now, and can be used independently. `testData.num` is of type number, but `test2.num` doesn't exist (according to the type).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUDOwBOAuNmCWAdgOZQC+AUOQMYD2B6UwE6AjDnIiutlAOTeEivADRQCAVwC2OFgCYAzGUq16wRs2CyAIgENgOhMlw9++YiLFSZCpSoZN0s9oYebd+oA)

---

The exact same rules apply here and this works without issue:

```
const map = new WeakMap<String, Base>()
const data = {
    prop1: 'value1',
    prop2: 'value2'
}
map.set('key1', data)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=22&pln=9&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChkHIAOUA9kQIwBcyGYUoA5rgL666iSyIoAi0wAG4QAJsggAPSCBEY0mHPkIlyAJhp0GIZm1wJSIOsgC2cIsgC8yEBADuyAOoQ4AawCyZgDwBlekwA08lgAfAAUAJR6BkYicGBwlsh4hMRklDQA5IJwADYArhAUGf5KBCpE6shZuQWqGay4pkQAdFhgoRkuEACeRYGx8eFAA)

---

TL;DR: When you assign an object literal to a type that would *immediately* lose some of the properties in that literal, typescript assumes that's a mistake since you could never access those properties directly after the initial assignment.

---

If you really want to capture extra unknown properties, you should do so in a type safe way. Like say with generics:

```
function makeThing<T extends { str: string }>(data: T): T {
  return data
}

const thing = makeThing({ str: 'string', num: 123 })
thing.num // safe
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwIYGsCmAVAFjMAcwB5tFMAPKTMAEwGdEBvReqAJwC5WODDEAvgD4AFLVRRU3bAEppzAFCJE7TFBDsk4yQoEKFEBG0RR8RRAF4UGHGcIiWbLogDkTvi4A0iMCGTcARgAmAGZBGQVTPgA6X2REAHoE1lRgTCA)

---

Your question has quite different code in it than when I first answered.

You can "solve" this case by making the `add()` function generic.

```
class Collection<T> {
  items: T[] = []
  add<U extends T>(item: U): U {
    this.items.push(item)
    return item
  }
}
```

Now instead of `add()` accepting a `T`, it now accepts a `T` or a subtype of `T`. This tells Typescript that the extra properties are not being discarded, since they will be returned by the methods return type.

Testing it out:

```
const col = new Collection<Base>()
const addedItem = col.add({
    prop1: 'value1',
    prop2: 'value2'
})
addedItem.prop1 // works
addedItem.prop2 // works

col.items[0].prop1 // works
col.items[0].prop2 // type error
;(col.items[0] as Derived).prop2 // works
```

But, again, this isn't a great idea. Because if you didn't actually add `prop2` because the `add` method doesn't require it, then you have no guard against assuming that the property exists.

Purposefully stuffing data into a type that lacks the properties for that data, only to fish it out later with unsafe casts seems like a bad plan to me.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChkHIAOUA9kQIwBcyGYUoA5rgL666iSyIoAi0wAG4QAJsggAPSCBEY0mHPkIlyAJhp0GIZm1wIANpjkBhUvv0QEYYKRAAeACoA+ZHgLBIAWww0HAbQBdZABeZEClOBEROwBVcSkIGTlnAAoPCE8aGIBKLNclAjAAC2AMADp07zKiAFcMIrSvbILkKAgwGqgQZEqlNl0EWzpkQf0Q5BAIAHdkU3NLa1s7dCwnFObBkGHIkVEASS9x0bKdlLdlMkoaAHJBOH0aiAprgBoWlSJ1ZFv7x9Vr1jNHb7LzVS4UZAAekhyCmpCgAGsMLhgSIDhkwWooTC4YjkXozBUvBg-AAGAKYyjY2HwpEE-REjIk8mU1TUsAATyIKGgZCguAA3CljpVmUFMMh+AxhCJsqzqbikUA)

Comment: Not with type safety you can't, which is why you had to cast to `any` there. And that's the point. It's there in the actual value, but its absent in the type. This one of those weird things that exist because Typescript compiles to javascript, and javascript has no types. Typescript exists to make javascript more strict. And this is part of that strictness.

Comment: Let me try that again: You can definitely access those properties after the initial assignment: `console.log((map.get('key1') as Derived).prop2)`

Comment: Not with type safety you can't. Casting with `as` is not type safe. It tells the compiler that you, the programmer, believe that this value is actually a more specific subtype of what the compiler think it is, and you, the programmer, might be wrong, and Typescript isn't going to check you on it. An example how a simple `as` can silently break your program: https://tsplay.dev/m3aYyw

Comment: Well, technically, I didn't ask for type safety. There are ways of making your code not break even without type safety (https://tsplay.dev/wX2pQm). Also, using generics is exactly what I was going for—it's even in the title of the question! But I need to be able to specify extended types when instantiating a new class, not when defining a function. Anyway to use generics in the example in the question?

Comment: I've updated the end of my answer to actually answer your updated question. At least I think it does. Still wouldn't recommend this, though.